# How to make borders glow in a 2D game?

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, post-processing, glow, unity-shader-graph

How can I make the borders (stationary / non moving) of my 2d Unity game glow?

I need a method that is not so expensive. I've read that post processing is very expensive, but I quite liked adding bloom to my scene. It was pretty straight forward.

But now I'm reading that one shouldn't use it, it's expensive, not so good etc.

Comment: Instead of listening to Internet hearsay, just **try it** and *profile it*. That is the only way you will ever learn whether a particular technique is efficient enough for your needs when used in the context of your game on your target hardware. Nobody else's opinion matters if you have concrete profiling data showing it works. If you like the post process bloom approach, just use it. If your measurements show it's too expensive for your needs, post a question here asking for help solving that demonstrated problem.

Comment: [Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime achieved some beautiful glowing effects in 3D by simply saving these glowing gradients into their textures](http://www.asteroidbase.com/devlog/6-2-5d-rendering-challenges/#more-378). If you need tips on achieving a specific look, it would help to edit your question to include an example of the appearance that you want to create.

Comment: thanks mate, yes i'll do that and see for myself.

Comment: "Too expensive" depends on your platform. On mobile, it's possible that bloom will hurt performance or increase battery drain, but it depends on the device and how complex your graphics are. If you're targeting PC, bloom is not likely to have a noticeable negative impact on performance on most systems. And you can always add an option to turn it on and off.

Comment: I'm targeting mobile devices. And need bloom just for the borders. for example The snake game, where if you touch the border you die. it is as simple as that. In my case i just want these borders to glow.